# Can you run an UPDATE and WITH together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run an update on a table, but get an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
```

The query is:

```
WITH
  first_users AS (
    select min(created_at) as first_at,
    company_id as company_id
    from users
    group by company_id
  )

UPDATE companies
 SET first_seen_at = LEAST(first_seen_at,
    (SELECT first_at FROM first_users WHERE id = first_users.company_id)
 );
```

Can you not run UPDATEs and WITHs together? Seems weird.

My query is actually slightly more complex, which is why I am using the with syntax. When I run SELECT * FROM first_users instead of UPDATE, it works, so there's something wrong  with the UPDATE keyword or something.

Comment: Postgres definitely supports `with` for `update` (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) . . . Since version 9.1.  Older versions don't support this functionality.

Comment: can you "join" companies and first_users, and do a "case when" instead?

Comment: UPDATE c SET c.first_seen_at = CASE WHEN c.first_seen_at > u.first_at THEN u.first_at ELSE c.first_seen_at END FROM first_users u INNER JOIN companies c ON u.company_id = c.id

Comment: Edit your question, and paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Please use the structure of your actual tables. I guessed at your table structure based on the UPDATE statement, and I got no syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing this to an `update . . . from` in any case.  There is no reason to update records that do not match.  So:

```
update companies
   set first_seen_at = u.first_at
   from (select company_id, min(created_at) as first_at
         from users
         group by company_id
        ) u
   where companies.id = u.company_id and
         u.first_seen_at < companies.first_seen_at;
```

Postgres started supporting CTEs with updates in version 9.1 (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html vs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html).  This method is better because it filters the rows before the update.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' . . . Do you have the tables on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: a) No, I haven't been able to use SQL Fiddle for ages. b) I *didn't* get syntax errors with your update statement; I got run-time errors. c) I didn't keep the tables, but I probably used something like  `create table users (created_at timestamp, company_id integer); create table companies (id integer, first_seen_at timestamp);` d) I'm really too sleepy to be on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' . . . There were two errors because `company_id` was selected twice in the subquery and the field name was wrong on the update.

Comment: ERROR: relation "u" does not exist

Comment: @Jeff . . . `u` is defined in the `from` clause, so I'm confused why it would not be recognized.

Answer (score -3):

Try encapsulating the query qith BEGIN/END. I don't know about PostgreSql, but MsSql does not accept WITH without BEGIN/END...